# Why does FLV load much faster than MP4?

Tags: webserver, streaming, video-streaming

I have a website where I stream my own videos, I use 2 video formats: MP4 and FLV they both have almost the same size
I notice that FLV load almost instantly but the MP4 takes like 35-60 seconds before it start playing

Media info:

MP4:

http://pastebin.com/kCET5YKP

FLV:

http://pastebin.com/tfKgZEBg

Tested with Apache and Litespeed web-server

Server config:

CPU: Intel Xeon E3

RAM: 8GB

HDD: 1TB

Network: 1Gbps dedicated

Comment: Can you give us more information?  What kind of server is serving webpages and videos?  What is that server's config?

Comment: Updated, is there any specific informations I need to provide?

Comment: @Webdop The odd thing here, that your FLV is not a real FLV ! It's like the same file with FLV extension !! Could you put these videos somewhere or similar ones to test it, or maybe could you provide a link to see it directly online ?

Answer (score 0):

first, you should understand that flv is mainly used to live streaming and mp4 for vod(video-on-demand). generally,  mp4 format has a big header contains metadata of all frames, so the player start playing it until download entire headers(many boxes).But flv has a little bit header(codec data), each tag contains a frame and tag's header describe tagtype, codecID, pts, dts.... It's similar to TS.

On the other hand, may be related to behavior of the player.

My English is very poor, please bear with me.

Comment: It's wrong that FLV is mainly used for live streaming, take a look on this [list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_video_hosting_services#Streaming_video_technical_information).

Comment: As used herein, the "mainly" is inaccurate, it should be used live or vod FLV.

Comment: The [list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_video_hosting_services#Streaming_video_technical_information) what's meaning and what's to tell us, FLV only be used for vod ?

Comment: No, why you insist to use "mainly" and "only" ? What I meant is that FLV is used for VOD and live streaming.